Session Parameter - Snowflake Connector from Python
Could you please guide the purpose of using session_parameters in a snowflake connector using Python?
Just trying to understand the purpose of this parameter and real time usage.
 con = snowflake.connector.connect(user=user,  account=account, private_key=pkb,  session_parameters={'QUERY_TAG': 'data_load.'})

I have no issues / errors, just wondering what the real time usage of session_parameters is.

A connection creates a session and you can set parameters values in the context of that session.
In your example, all queries executed during the session will be tagged with the string “data_load“
